# audit trail in database username not registering

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

I'm currently trying to make a basic store database using Microsoft Access with VisualBasic coding and have created a fully functioning audit trail using a mix of online tutorials. However, I am very new to visual basic and have only two to three weeks of experience with it.

Due to this, I am Having a hard time with the UserName part of the audit as it is giving me the computers account username instead of the one used in the database login.

the current code I am using:

```vb
Sub AuditChanges(IDField As String, UserAction As String)
      On Error GoTo AuditChanges_Err
    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim ctl As Control
    Dim datTimeCheck As Date
    Dim strUserID As String
    Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection
    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
    rst.Open "SELECT * FROM tblAuditTrail", cnn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
    datTimeCheck = Now()
    strUserID = Environ("USERNAME")
    Dim Test As String
    Test = "EDIT"
    Select Case UserAction
        Case Test
            For Each ctl In Screen.ActiveForm.Controls
                If ctl.Tag = "Audit" Then
                    If Nz(ctl.Value) <> Nz(ctl.OldValue) Then
                        With rst
                            .AddNew
                            ![DateTime] = datTimeCheck
                            ![UserName] = strUserID
                            ![FormName] = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
                            ![Action] = UserAction
                            ![RecordID] = Screen.ActiveForm.Controls(IDField).Value
                            ![FieldName] = ctl.ControlSource
                            ![OldValue] = ctl.OldValue
                            ![NewValue] = ctl.Value
                            .Update
                        End With
                    End If
                End If
            Next ctl
        Case Else
            With rst
                .AddNew
                ![DateTime] = datTimeCheck
                ![UserName] = strUserID
                ![FormName] = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
                ![Action] = UserAction
                ![RecordID] = Screen.ActiveForm.Controls(IDField).Value
                .Update
            End With
    End Select
AuditChanges_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    rst.Close
    cnn.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cnn = Nothing
    Exit Sub
AuditChanges_Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "ERROR!"
    Resume AuditChanges_Exit
End Sub
```

Any assistance will be deeply appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: `Environ("username")` will give you the name of the user logged in. Maybe `Application.CurrentUser` is what you are looking for your access app? If you have a custom logon, you could make a small table to record the user details you need. E.g. you could relate the user logged in name to some other identifier.

Comment: thank you for replying. i will give that a try

Comment: that's a good improvement.

Comment: Hope it helps. :)

Comment: it has it not exactly giving me the username, it's giving me the security level of the user. admin, user that sort of thing but it is better than before

Answer (score 1):

As @RyanWildry mentions, your custom login will dictate how to retrieve the current database user name. Assuming a form login, there are a few ways to retrieve the current user to be used in audit trail:

1. **TABLE**: Store user in table such as a one-row *CurrentUser* which updates after successful login:

   ```
   User      StartTime
   Jane Doe  2018-12-31 12:00
   ```

   Action query to be triggered after successful login:

   ```sql
   UPDATE [CurrentUser] SET [User] = Forms!DatabaseLogin!UserName, StartTime = Now();
   ```

   Then in your audit trail, assign to table with `DLookUp`, replacing `Environ("UserName")`:

   ```
   ...
   strUserID = DLookUp("[User]", "[CurrentUser]")
   ...
   ```
2. **FORM**: Use the very login form, particularly a hidden one that user does not see. After user enters credentials, render the database login form hidden so it remains available for retrieval of textbox values:

   ```
   Forms!DatabaseLogin.Visible = True
   ```

   Then in your audit trail, assign to form value, replacing `Environ("UserName")`:

   ```
   ...
   strUserID = Forms!DatabaseLogin!UserName
   ...
   ```
3. **VARIABLE**: Use a global VBA variable in a standard module (i.e., not behind any form/report) that is set after login and remains throughout session of application or reset with next user:

   ```
   Option Compare Database              ' MS ACCESS DEFAULT
   Option Explicit                      ' BEST PRACTICE TO ADD

   Public CurrentUserName As String     ' PLACE OUTSIDE OF ANY FUNCTION/SUB

   ' CALL SUB ROUTINE AFTER LOGIN
   Sub SetUser()
       CurrentUserName = Forms!DatabaseLogin!UserName
   End SetUser
   ```

   Then in your audit trail, assign to global variable, replacing `Environ("UserName")`:

   ```
   ...
   strUserID = CurrentUserName
   ...
   ```

Comment: thank you very much both of you have helped me out with this

Comment: I am sorry but your instructions are a bit confusing, you want me to replace Environ("UserName") three times?

Comment: also  I have tried  UPDATE CurrentUser SET [User] = Forms!DatabaseLogin!UserName, StartTime = Now(); but all i get is a syntax error

Comment: reattempted that UPDATE CurrentUser SET [User] = Forms!DatabaseLogin!UserName, StartTime = Now(); code again an now says thatSET is a compile error and a unexpeted end of statment

Comment: These are three **different** solutions to the same problem. Simply pick one and replace `Envrion("UserName")` once. How are you running the query? Do you have such a table with fields, form, and textbox? Be sure to adjust name to actuals. `CurrentUser` is actually a [reserved, system word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/286335/list-of-reserved-words-in-access-2002-and-in-later-versions-of-access), so wrap in brackets: `[CurrentUser]`